# how does self instantiating mechanism/concept works in java?

Tags: java, oop

I'm new to Java and to OOP, so some things below may sound silly, but...

I understand a situation when i have two classes (two different types) and one does whatever it wants with the instance of the other one, like

```
class A { ... }

class B { 
   ...
   public A someMethod() { 
      return new A;
   }
   ...
}
```

At the point when B's method is declaring some code to work with A, the A type is pretty defined and complete and thus one thing can use/make something with another. That all is pretty logical for me at this point.

But I was thinking about the case when a class declaration has a method in it that works with the instance of its own type. How that is possible? I would probably imagine some 'loop', but it's not a loop. How the method can have a code about something that is not 'complete' or completely known at the moment when the code is being written.

Sorry if i made some muddled description, I just couldn't find better words to explain this. Absolutely can't fit this concept into my head. Could somebody please explain?

UPDATE: i found some snippet that may help you to understand my problem. The code in the class below does not create instance of itself, but it casts the absolutely other object to the its (RectanglePlus') type...

```
public class RectanglePlus 
    implements Relatable {
    ...

    // four constructors
    public RectanglePlus() {
        origin = new Point(0, 0);
    }
    ...
    // a method required to implement
    // the Relatable interface
    public int isLargerThan(Relatable other) {
        RectanglePlus otherRect 
            = (RectanglePlus)other;
        if (this.getArea() < otherRect.getArea())
            return -1;
        else if (this.getArea() > otherRect.getArea())
            return 1;
        else
            return 0;               
    }
}
```

Copyright © 2008, 2010 Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved. Use is subject to license terms.

Comment: I have a feeling you're mixing up classes and instances of classes.

Comment: Can you give some example code to show what you're talking about?

Comment: @DmitryBerdnikov: Please edit your question to include that code.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, sorry, have added the example

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why Can You Instantiate a Class within its Definition?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5186214/why-can-you-instantiate-a-class-within-its-definition)

Comment: @lwburk i've seen that before, but didn't find an answer for myself there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

During compilation, this is done by having a [multi-pass compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-pass_compiler) that first analyzes class and method signatures before dealing with individual statements.

During runtime, class loading and initialization happens when the class is first used and usually before any of its code is executed. Thus, when a method of the class is executed, its 
entire structure and code have been initialized.

But you are right that things *can* get muddled with code that is executed during class initialization, such as static initializer blocks and initial assignments to static fields. If these call methods of the class, such methods are executed within a not-yet fully initialized class context, which can cause unexpected behaviour.

Comment: you answer has helped me to rephrase what i wanted to find out: when i was writing my initial question i was thinking that the compiler goes to analyze the type, then goes to analyze the code inside of its methods and sees !that type again! inside. And it needs to treat it as something, but it's already in the middle of analyzing it.. that's why i used a word 'loop' above. i just want to understand what a compiler (or jvm, or whatever else) understands under the type while being analyzing some part of this type which has this type inside...

Comment: @Dmitry: the point is that the *structure* of the type is all that's needed to do everything the compiler has to do when it encounters the type being used inside a method.

Answer (score 2):

The compilers are intelligent enough and they can deal with a class that acts on an instance of itself.

I'm not sure exactly how it's done, but I guess first the compiler just gets an overview of the class and makes a list of the methods of that class.  Then it look in detail at the code of each method, and if one of the method calls another method on an instance of the class, the compiler can tell if it's valid  or not.

Answer (score 0):

By the time you write the code to call `otherRect.getArea()` inside of `isLargerThan` (and before that code is ever executed) the compiler will have already read the definition of `RectanglePlus` and is therefore aware that instances of that class have access to a method called `getArea`.

It doesn't matter that the object being instantiated is of the same type as the class the invocation resides in. This necessarily implies some ordering of operations (i.e. the compiler must read a class's method signatures *before* it attempts to read their bodies).

Think of it this way: if the compiler didn't do this sort of thing, then how would you ever even **call one method from inside another in the same class** (since that class wouldn't be "complete", in your terms, at the time you were writing that call)?

Comment: Ok, but what does it understand under the type while being analyzing the code of the method iside of this same type (which contains that type inside)?

Comment: Sorry, not sure I understand the question.