# Why does this class instantiate its own object within the class itself?

Tags: c#, class, interface, instantiation

With reference to interfaces, I have come across the following code sample. Why does this class instantiate its own object within the main method? Is it a valid theory or code convention in C# and Java? (compiler didn't complaine..but I am curious)

```
using System;

interface IParentInterface
{
    void ParentInterfaceMethod();
}

interface IMyInterface : IParentInterface
{
    void MethodToImplement();
}

class InterfaceImplementer : IMyInterface
{
    static void Main()
    {
        InterfaceImplementer iImp = new InterfaceImplementer();
        iImp.MethodToImplement();
        iImp.ParentInterfaceMethod();
    }

    public void MethodToImplement()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MethodToImplement() called.");
    }

    public void ParentInterfaceMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ParentInterfaceMethod() called.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it shouldn't do so? It's perfectly valid in both C# and Java.

Comment: But it certainly looks strange to put the main method in a class that implements an interface. Personally, I wouldn't do that.

Comment: @Jon Skeet said it's perfectly valid - yes the compiler didn't complain. Daniel Hilgarth said it looks odd (more less what I felt). Can either of you kindly direct me to a code sample reference or an article to read up/experiement on: *"looks strange to put the main method in a class that implements an interface"*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method 'main' is static hence it does not reference any InterfaceImplementer instance. To call instance methods it needs to create an instance.

Static method called 'main' is not, as far as i know, any known convention.

If this is an attempt to have a singleton the main method should be replaced with a static constructor and be backed by a private InterfaceImplementer variable

To name a method "Main" that will invoke two methods does not seem a good name choice.

**EDIT to answer comments**

To fully understand the singleton pattern i strongly advise on reading [this](http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx)

A method named "Main" does not help the caller to understand whatever the method is doing. I would choose 'Run', 'Initialize', 'Invoke'.

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by this: *"Static method called 'main' is not, as far as i know, any known convention."*? What do you mean by a singleton attempt? All I understand here that author tries to show how to implement from multiple interfaces and a parent class describing interfaces. Can you please show a sample code for this: *"If this is an attempt to have a singleton the main method should be replaced with a static constructor and be backed by a private InterfaceImplementer variable"*? I am a beginner trying to catch up on these theory with coding.

Comment: @Luis: It'll be called main so it's the entry point of the program

Comment: I found [this to be helpful in terms of instantiating an object within own class.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5186214/why-can-you-instantiate-a-class-within-its-definition). But I am not convinced much for the involvment of interfaces here. I assume these interfaces act like any other interfaces or class with methods without implementations.

Comment: Class methods without implementations ==> abstract classes
When you inherit from a class you are compromising yourself with its inheritance chain: all properties,methods and events.
A class never inherits from an interface it rather claims to implement it. It almost like inheriting from an abstract class but you are not limited to just one "parent" and you are also not bound to whatever that parent is, therefore you can have different classes implementing the same interface that not in the same inheritance chain

Answer (score 1):

Likely that was from a tutorial.

The code was to run as a console application, which must have a static `Main` method, which is where program execution starts.

So when you run the program with that class it'll test the 2 methods.
The class creates an instance of its self in the main method because it's not a static class its self.

It would be less confusing if there was a separate `program` class with the `static main` method as is normally the case.

Comment: Yes it's from a tutorial found online. I assume the author was putting more stress on showing how to implement interfaces in child class that inherits them. So perhaps he took the approach of [one-class-experiment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5186214/why-can-you-instantiate-a-class-within-its-definition). I found this post to read further.