# Instantiating an object within its own class

Tags: php

I was trying to figure out if I can instantiate a class within its own constructor and I came across this:

[Why Can You Instantiate a Class within its Definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5186214/why-can-you-instantiate-a-class-within-its-definition).

Then I tried the same thing in PHP:

```
Class someClass {
 function __construct() {
  $objNew = new someClass();
  $objNew->doit();
 }

  function doit() {
   echo "Do it man!\n";
  }
}

$oNew = new someClass();
```

Everytime I tried to run this I got a "Segmentation Fault" error.....
With reference to the above code and even the link posted above, I want to think that instantiating a class within its own constructor would cause an infinite number of objects to get created (until the server crashes, of course!).....any thoughts on what is going on above? Why is it ok to do this in Java and (perhaps) not in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the same thing. On the question [Why Can You Instantiate a Class within its Definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5186214/why-can-you-instantiate-a-class-within-its-definition), a **static** method is used to instantiate his class. Static methods are stored with the class definition (like a blueprint) inside the heap memory and do not require to be instantiated.

You could create a static method, and this one will have to create a new instance of your class:

```
Class someClass {
  function __construct() {
    $this->doit();
  }

  static function createSomeClass() {
    return new someClass();
  } 

  function doit() {
    echo "Do it man!\n";
  }
}

$oNew = someClass::createSomeClass();
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am not very good with Java, but here goes: I though whenever a new object is created in Java, the JVM looks for the "public static void main" function to get going.....in that case, when I create a new object of the same class within its constructor, wouldn't that call the "main" function of its own class within which the object is recreated which would then call the "main" function recursively??

Comment: Your program gives Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' on line 8 error

Answer (score 1):

Php is not compiled but interpreted. Java is compiled and after this executed. So the class itself is not yet all defined and you call it again in php so this throws an error.

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is call that method when object is instantiated. Then, there's no meaning of doing this `$objNew = new someClass();`. Its useless. Simply, do this:

```
class someClass {
  function __construct() {
    $this->doit();
  }

  function doit() {
   echo "Do it man!\n";
  }
}

$oNew = new someClass();
```

Comment: Of course I could do this :) However, the question is a part of a large class with multiple functions. The class processes some data and towards the end, some data is left unprocessed for which I would like to instantiate the class again and send the unprocessed data to the class again for processing (recursive processing....though only ONE level deep!) . There are other ways of doing this; but I thought instantiating the class again and sending it the remaining (unprocessed) data would be "more elegant"!

Answer (score 0):

Below is the right solution for you

```
<?php
Class someClass {
 function __construct() {
  $this->doit();
 }

  function doit() {
   echo "Do it man!\n";
  }
}

$oNew = new someClass();
?>
```